# Why does validation fail when connecting to a server by IP address instead of hostname?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am getting the bad certificate error while accessing the server using IP address instead DNS name.

Is this functionality newly introduced in tls1.1. and tls 1.2?  It would be good if someone would point out OpenSSL code where it fails and return the bad certificate error.

Comment: In your case the certificate was issued against "the.domain.com" which is a completely different value from an IP address string, this is fundamental to how certificates work.  Why don't you just connect to the domain name?

Comment: which version of openssl contains the validation of hostname

Answer (score 6):

> Why do we get bad certificate error while accessing the server using IP address instead dns name?

It depends on the issuing/validation policies, user agents, and the version of OpenSSL you are using. So to give you a precise answer, we need to know more about your configuration.

Generally speaking, suppose ***`www.example.com`*** has a IP address of ***`www.xxx.yyy.zzz`***. If you connect via ***`https://www.example.com/...`***, then the connection should succeed. If you connect *using a browser* via ***`https://www.xxx.yyy.zzz/...`*** then it should always fail. If you connect *using another user agent* via ***`https://www.xxx.yyy.zzz/...`*** then it should succeed if the certificate includes ***`www.xxx.yyy.zzz`***; and fail otherwise.

***Issuing/Validation Policies***

There are two bodies which dominate issuing/validation policies. They are the [CA/Browser Forum](http://cabforum.org/), and the [Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF)](https://www.ietf.org/).

Browsers, Like Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, follow the [CA/B Baseline Requirements](http://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements/) (CA/B BR).

Other user agents, like cURL and Wget, follow IETF issuing and validation policies, like [RFC 5280, Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) and [RFC 6125, Representation and Verification of Domain-Based Application Service Identity within Internet Public Key Infrastructure Using X.509 (PKIX) Certificates in the Context of Transport Layer Security (TLS)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6125.txt). The RFCs are more relaxed that CA/B issuing policies.

***User Agents***

Different user agents have different policies that apply to DNS names. Some want a traditional hostname found in DNS, while others allow IP addresses.

Browsers only allow DNS hostnames in the *Subject Alternate Name (SAN)*. If the hostname is missing from the SAN, then the match *will not* occur. Putting the server name in the *Common Name* is a waste of time and energy because browsers require host names in the SAN.

Browsers ***do not*** match a public IP address in the SAN. They will *sometimes* allow a Private IP from [RFC 1918, Address Allocation for Private Internets](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt).

Other user agents allow any name in the *Subject Alternate Name (SAN)*. They also will match a name in both the *Common Name (CN)* and the *Subject Alternate Name (SAN)*. Names include a DNS name like ***`www.example.com`***, a public IP address, a private IP address like ***`192.168.10.10`*** and a local name like ***`localhost`*** and ***`localhost.localdomain`***.

***OpenSSL Version***

OpenSSL version 1.0.2 and below ***did not*** perform hostname validation. That is, you had to perform the matching yourself. If you did not perform hostname validation yourself, then it appeared the connection always succeeded. Also see [Hostname Validation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation) and [TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

OpenSSL 1.1.0 and above perform hostname matching. If you switch to 1.1.0, then you should begin experiencing failures *if* you were not performing hostname matching youself or you were not strictly following issuing policies.

---

> It would be good if someone would point out OpenSSL code where it fails and return the bad certificate error.

The check-ins occurred in early-2015, and they have been available in Master (i.e., 1.1.0-dev) since that time. The code was also available in 1.0.2, but you had to perform special actions. The routines were not available in 1.0.1 or below. Also see [Hostname Validation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation) on the OpenSSL wiki. I don't have the Git check-ins because I'm on a Windows machine at the moment.

---

More information of the rules for names and their locations can be found at [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/608639). There are at least four or six more documents covering them, like how things need to be presented for [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797) and [Public Key Pinning with Overrides for HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7469).

Comment: Is there any way to connect to a let's say private IP-address but tell the agent that connects to it that it expects the CN to be "someCNname.com"? Or is this agent dependent. I know that for mbedtls for example you can specify the server address (server_addr) as 192.168.210.5 for example, but if you also specify the server name (server_name) as "theservername.com" for example, the connection will succeed if the certificate's CN was "theservername.com".